# How to set pandas tz_localize properly?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does this "pythonic" code not work on the `tz_localize()` line?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{ "Localtime":"2016-01-01 12:00:00", "Timezone":"Europe/London" }, 
                   { "Localtime":"2016-01-01 12:00:00", "Timezone":"Europe/Paris" }])

df['UtcDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Localtime']).tz_localize(df['Timezone'])
df
```

I am looking for some code that is prettier than the following code (which works fine btw):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{ "Localtime":"2016-01-01 12:00:00", "Timezone":"Europe/London" },
                   { "Localtime":"2016-01-01 12:00:00", "Timezone":"Europe/Paris" }])

df['UtcDateTime'] = 'NA'
i=0
for ts in df.Localtime:
    ts1 = pd.to_datetime(ts).tz_localize(df.Timezone[i])
    df['UtcDateTime'][i] = ts1
    i=i+1
df
```

Expected result:

```
    Localtime           Timezone        UtcDateTime
0   2016-01-01 12:00:00 Europe/London   2016-01-01 12:00:00+00:00
1   2016-01-01 12:00:00 Europe/Paris    2016-01-01 12:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: Is there a way to display `2016-01-01 13:00:00` instead of `2016-01-01 12:00:00+01:00`?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is not working because `tz_localize()` expects to apply a single timezone to multiple values in a series.  To make your loop a bit cleaner, you can use `apply()` as:

**Code:**

```
def localize_ts(row):
    return pd.to_datetime(row['Localtime']).tz_localize(row['Timezone'])

df['UtcDateTime'] = df.apply(localize_ts, axis=1)
```

**Produces:**

```
             Localtime       Timezone                UtcDateTime
0  2016-01-01 12:00:00  Europe/London  2016-01-01 12:00:00+00:00
1  2016-01-01 12:00:00   Europe/Paris  2016-01-01 12:00:00+01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to just opt for [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.Localtime).tz_localize(x.Timezone), axis=1)
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df['UtcDateTime'] = df.apply(lambda x:  pd.to_datetime(x.Localtime).tz_localize(x.Timezone), axis=1)

>>> df
             Localtime       Timezone                UtcDateTime
0  2016-01-01 12:00:00  Europe/London  2016-01-01 12:00:00+00:00
1  2016-01-01 12:00:00   Europe/Paris  2016-01-01 12:00:00+01:00
```

---

The reason why your shorter approach doesn't work is that indeed `tz_localize` requires an *index* to act upon, not values. I would suggest you convert it to a DatetimeIndex with something like `pd.DatetimeIndex`,
however then still, `tz_localize` accepts only a single time zone and so you'll end up applying over rows anyways.